# With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("connection"). _ OLEDBConnection

Tags: excel, vba, connection

This keeps saying subscript out of range. Anyone know why?

(The "connection" is just something that I put there so I didn't enter in my own connection)

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the underscore should be there.

Try listing the connection-names to ensure that you have supplied it *exactly*

```
Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
    Debug.Print conn.Name
Next conn
```

If there is only one connection you could use `Connections(1)`, although it is preferable to use the name.